# Observable do IO and following flow on IO schedulre

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

I saw a weird behavior on RxJava with the following code:

```
package com.hotels.guestreview.infrastructure.repository;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    import rx.Observable;
    import rx.functions.Action1;
    import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;


    import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;
    import rx.Observable;
    import rx.functions.Action1;
    import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final Main m = new Main();
            m.run();
        }

        public void run() {
            final List<String> result = Observable.from(new Integer[]{4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3})
                    .doOnNext(debug("Init"))
                    .flatMap(i -> Observable.defer(() -> toRandomList(i)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                    .doOnNext(debug("defer"))
                    .flatMap(this::chooseString)
                    .doOnNext(debug("chooseString"))
                    .toList()
                    .doOnNext(debug("list"))
                    .toBlocking()
                    .single();
            System.out.println("\nresult = " + result);
        }


        public static Observable<List<String>> toRandomList(Integer n) {
            debug("perform IO").call(n);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(3000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            debug("IO done").call(n);
            final List<String> result = Stream.iterate(0, t -> t + 1)
                .map(i -> RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(n))
                .limit(n)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return Observable.just(result);
        }

        public Observable<String> chooseString(List<String> list) {
            // guilty code
            /*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(3000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */
            // end guilty code
            if (Math.random() > .3) {
                return Observable.just(list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size())));
            }
            else {
                return Observable.empty();
            }
        }

        public static <T> Action1<T> debug(String s) {
            return o -> System.out.println(o + " | " + s + " | " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }
```

I'm trying to execute the method `toRandomList` on the *io* scheduler, and everything works fine with the *guilty code* commented, having each emission and following flow of `toRandomList` on a separate thread.
If I remove the comment (adding the sleep) of the `guilty code` in the `chooseString` method, each step after the `toRandomList` is executed on the same thread.
Why is this happening? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in the flat map, should be refactored as:

```
Observable.from(new Integer[]{4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3})
                .doOnNext(debug("Init"))
                .flatMap(i -> Observable.defer(() -> toRandomList(i))
                      .doOnNext(debug("defer"))
                      .flatMap(this::chooseString)
                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                )
```

In this way all the subflow defined internally at the `flatMap` in which is called the `subscribeOn` are executed on a thread of the `Scheduler` choosen.

Then as @Dmitry pointed out in his response a better approach is use the `fromCallable` instead of the combination of `defer` and `just`/`empty`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using `Observable.just` to create your stream inside `toRandomList`. `Observable.just` creates a stream from **already calculated** value. But what you want is to do some calculations before returning a value, so you need to use a different operator. `Observable.fromCallable` for example:

```
public static Observable<List<String>> toRandomList(Integer n) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        debug("perform IO").call(n);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(3000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        debug("IO done").call(n);

        return Stream.iterate(0, t -> t + 1)
                .map(i -> "1")
                .limit(n)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    });
}
```

Comment: I thought that the "future" calculation was managed here:
```.flatMap(i -> Observable.defer(() -> toRandomList(i)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))``` using the `defer`.  
Should I remove the `defer` if I use the `fromCallable`?

Comment: Yes, you can just use `.flatMap(i -> toRandomList(i).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))`

Comment: It doesn't work, all the steps from the `debug("defer")` are executed on the same thread, and the `chooseString` becomes a bottleneck

Comment: You can move `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` from here `.flatMap(i -> Observable.defer(() -> toRandomList(i)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))` to the beginning of the stream right after `Observable.from(new Integer[]{4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3})`

Comment: I found the problem is in the flow defined out of the `flatMap` check my response for what I mean. Thanks!